# How does Chromecast Work?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, network-programming, chromecast

I am trying to learn some networking basics. I want know how chrome cast works?. They say it uses the internet attached to the laptop/desktop and connects to the nearest chromecast dongle device. But How does it get the IP address of dongle device? There could be many such devices and many such chrome cast clients in the surroundings. How does this work? One article I saw on internet which says, it uses some local private address and does some DNS magic to get to the device. Can someone please explain me how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of articles explaining it, the discovery portion is UPnP based.